# Issues with dynamic height on CdkDropList

Tags: angular, angular-cdk

I'm using CdkDragDrop to make a dynamic grid which can be restructured with drag and drop from the user. I created this StackBlitz to illustrate both my use case and the issue I'm facing https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rvv4g9.

When I have two elements on the same row I would like to drop one of the elements on an empty row to separate them and create a new row. To do this I inserted empty rows inbetween all rows, when you drag an item they are illustrated with a red background. Since the elements I'm dragging have a rather large height I would like the empty rows to start out small, and when inserting items into them, make them expand.

The issue I'm facing is if you drag for example the element "1" over the row between it and the "3", you can see the row expand, then continue to drag the "1" down below the "3", and you cannot drop the item there.

I think the "drop-area" is not recalculated, and is being blocked by another element which has expanded.

Does anyone know of a way to recalculate the drop-area or any other way in which I could solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom drag placeholder for this:

```
<div class="example-custom-placeholder" *cdkDragPlaceholder></div>
```

See my Stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vy9yvj

[image]